# ı was trying to make a calculator in c# console

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I want that the user ınputs a mathematical equation as string, than split them to chars then cast them into double so that I can use them but I am having troubles to cast char to double

```
public  void Cal()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the transaction without spaces");
            string transaction = Console.ReadLine();
            char[] characters = transaction.ToArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < characters.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(characters[i] + " ");
                if (i % 2 == 1)
                {
                    Convert.ToDouble(characters[i]);
                }
            }
            
        }
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Calculate calc = new Calculate();
            bool quit = false;
            
            while (quit == false)
            {
                calc.Cal();
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("to clear pres C to quit the app pres Q");
                Console.Write(" : ");
                string b = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if (b == "C")
                {
                    Console.Clear();
                }else 
                {

                    quit = true;
                    Console.ReadLine();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you expect as input? A _Transaction_ isn't very specific

Comment: math transaction like 34 * 5

Comment: Is it a simple/single, two-argument infix expression like that every time, or can it be `1 + 2 * 4` (and if the latter, what are the precedence rules - is the result of that `12` or `9`)? What are the allow operators? Does an expression like `34 / 5` result in `6` or `6.8`?

Comment: By the way, in normal nomenclature, that's an _expression_, not a _transaction_ and what you are doing is _parsing_ it and then _evaluating_ it. If you search for _math expression parser_, you'll probably find some sample code

Comment: One way to approach this problem is to define your tokens (in `34+5` there are three tokens, `34`, `+` and `5`, two of them representing numbers, and another representing an operator). You need to figure out what makes up a token (`5` is a number, is `-12.34`). Then figure out a grammar (in your case. `number` `operator` `number` make up an expression). Finally, you need a way of evaluating those expressions. As a final hint, you'll be happier if you use `decimal` rather than `double` as your primary numeric type (it's more exact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very simple math evaluator, you should step through the char[] to identify the operators first.  Then you could evaluate the expression by converting the char[] segments between operators, or outside the single operator, to a numerical type, and passing them as operands for each operator, and presenting the result. It's more complex if you are supporting parenthetic enclosures. (see below)

To convert the char[] segments between the operators, since you're using C#, you could either:

- Use your string "transaction" and call .Substring(startidx, endidx) limiting it to before or between the operators, and then call .Trim() to remove whitespace and return you a string. Ex: "string expression = transaction.Substring(0, opidx-1).Trim()" That string (of the number) can be sent to the double.Parse() function to return you the double value that you can evaluate with using the operator(s) and other values parsed and converted this way. Ex: "double val = double.Parse(expression)".
- Or you could call a function to step each char index in the range up to the operator, using char.IsNumber() to find the start and end of the range of non-whitespace, then might as well use the transaction string and .Substring with those indexes to output the string containing the number to parse, like above, with double.Parse(). Else you could append the number chars to a string.

If you wanted a more capable formula and expression parser, you would need to approach it a bit more sophisticatedly.

I once wrote a C# code parser, including a complete mathematical expression/formula parser. Parsing a potentially complex mathematical expression is an important step for a math evaluating software program. Parentheses can influence the order of evaluation.

Basically the steps I took, outside of identifying comments and literal zones (specific to a code parser), are to:

- Create an array of open and matching close parentheses indexes from within your expression. A recursive function is most efficient. Call a FindCloseParan function, giving it the open paran index, and if it finds an open paran before a close paran beyond it, it will call FindCloseParan again, else it can return the close paran char, allowing you to store each open paran's matching same level close paran in an array. Then you can later make calls to a GetCloseParan function for an open paran index to retrieve its matching level close paran index, without having to repeat use of a then potentially inefficient (overlapping work-repeating) recursive FindCloseParan function, and you can use the matching open and close paran indexes to run a parse expression function in each zone. (If you want a simple math evaluator with no parentheses support, you may omit this)
- Run a function to parse the logic expression. It should identify the next index of an operator (or AND or OR), and see if it is before the next open paran. If the next operator index is after a open paran, it should search for the next operator after the close paran at the same paran level as the open paran. If it finds any outside of parans, it should call the parse logic expression function to parse the expression on each side of each operator. If there is no operator, it can parse the block to store it as an expression class type. If there are multiple operators at the same parans enclosure level, it can store an index of each operator type in an array of operators, and an array of expression types which interleave with the operators. (Expression, Operator, Expression, Operator, Expression, etc.)

Identifying a char that could be the first char of an operator, leads to checking for a possible two character operator. From my code:

CSharpTypeWalker.firstcharoperatorsarrray = new char[] { '+', '-', '~', '*', '/', '%', '^', '!', '&', '|', '<', '>', '=', '?' };

CSharpTypeWalker.alloperatorsarray = new string[] { "+", "-", "~", "*", "/", "%", "^", "!", "&", "|", "<", ">", "<<", ">>", "&&", "||", "==", "!=", "<=", "=>", ">=", "=<", "?:", "+=", "-=", "++", "--" };